# How to edit multiple text files with a single command?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I want to remove the first line of multiple text files and replace it with another line. Is there a way to do this using the terminal?

I know how to use vim, is there a way to automate it with it? I want to avoid doing it manually (as in editing each file individually).

If possible I'd like to avoid installing new libraries (especially for something like that which i consider very simple - but I could be wrong).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use `sed` :

```
sed -i.bak '1s/^.*$/new line/' *.txt
```

This will replace the first line of all `.txt` files in the current directory with the text `new line`, change it to meet your need.

Also the original files will be backed up with `.bak` extension, if you don't want that just use :

```
sed -i '1s/^.*$/new line/' *.txt
```

Comment: Thank you! `sed` is actually what i was looking for!

Comment: @TomTsagk Glad i could help :)

Answer (score 15):

Well, using `vim` itself:

```
vim -Nesc 'bufdo call setline(1,"This is the replacement.") | wq' file1 file2 ...
```

What this does:

- [`setline (n, text)`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#%3Acall), well, is a function that sets line `n` to `text`.
- [`call`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#%3Acall) is needed to call functions.
- [`bufdo`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#%3Abufdo) is used to repeat a command across buffers (without a range, it acts on all buffers).
- `wq` saves and quits the buffer. We need to do this before moving on to the next buffer, so this command is chained to the `call` command using `|`.
- `-c cmd` runs `cmd` is a command-mode command after loading the first buffer.
- `Nes` turns on no-compatible, silent, ex-mode, which is better for non-interactive processing.

Benefits:

- The `setline` text content can be anything - an `&` in a `sed` replacement text can have unintended effects.

Comment: `sed` seems much easier to use, but it's really awesome that `vim` can do the same! Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: @TomTsagk well, I just wanted to illustrate how you could act across multiple files (`bufdo`). Consider you having the files already open and ... And to show an alternate to `1s/foo/bar/`.

Comment: Awesoming!!!  <3_<3

Answer (score 4):

A few other options:

- `awk` (needs a relatively new version of GNU `awk`)

  ```
  $ awk -i inplace -vline="new line" '(FNR==1){print line; next}1;' *.txt
  ```
- Perl/shell

  ```
  $ for f in *txt; do
      perl -i -lne '$.==1 ? print "new line" : print' "$f"
    done
  ```
- Shell/coreutils

  ```
  $ for f in *txt; do 
      ( echo "new line"; tail -n+2 "$f" ) > foo && mv foo "$f"; 
    done
  ```

Answer (score 2):

This script will do as you requested, placing the changed files in a new directory without actually changing the originals.

```
d=/tmp/cooked
mkdir $d
for f in *  #will match all files in current directory; adjust as desired
do
  echo "This is the new 1st line" > /${d}/${f}
  sed 1d ${f} >> /${d}/${f}
done
```

Comment: I was slow answering (tested my code)...and I like heemayl's solution a lot better!

Answer (score 1):

Using `gawk`

```
gawk -i inplace 'FNR==1 {$_="your_replacement"}; {print}' *.txt
```

---

*Example*

```
% cat foo.txt 
1
2
3
4

% cat bar.txt 
1
2
3
4

% gawk -i inplace 'FNR==1 {$_="your_replacement"}; {print}' *.txt

% cat foo.txt                                                    
your_replacement
2
3
4

% cat bar.txt                                                    
your_replacement
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 0):

The tail and cat commands would do this easily:

```
tail -n +1 $file > tmpfile
cat newfirstline tmpfile >$file
```

Wrap those in a suitable loop and perhaps use a proper and righteous temporary file instead of a hard-coded temporary file name. I believe bash and other shells have a syntax for creating temporary files.

The -n option of tail has two interpretations depending on whether the argument has a plus sign. If it has a plus sign then it means to show the tail of the file *starting at* the given line number. Otherwise the number is the number of lines, including the last line, that tail is supposed to output.

Answer (score 0):

[rpl](http://rpl.sourceforge.net/) is so much better than `sed`.

Oh my goodness, finally [a solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/251742/261675) that's straightforward:

```
rpl "myFlag=True" "myFlag=False" *.cfg
```